# How to setup access to ElasticDomain from different AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-vpc

I created an ElasticDomain in private subnet which has a VPC endpoint and a security group which allows access from port 443. We want to access this ElasticDomain from another AWS account's EC2 instance. But we are not able to do that.

1. We tried creating ElasticDomain with a public endpoint which is accessible from anywhere but is not the right option for us.
2. We are considering to use apache as a reverse proxy and then set up a VPC private-link on a consumer account. Is that a right approach?

Answer (score 0):

AWS PrivateLink via VPC and Network Load Balancer doesn't support ElasticDomain for now.

Check out the following two links:

1. [How to Control Access to Your Amazon Elasticsearch Service Domain](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-control-access-to-your-amazon-elasticsearch-service-domain/)
2. [AWS ElasticSearch write to account "A" from lambda in account "B"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46655097/aws-elasticsearch-write-to-account-a-from-lambda-in-account-b)

Comment: With this can we access elastic search services because when we tried to launch network load balancer we were not able to choose elastic domain over there or we were doing it wrong. Because we want to access the elastic search domain.

Comment: Mukul, you're right, I tried that myself and Network Load Balancer doesn't have support for ElasticDomain for now. I did some research and updated my answer with new the information.

Comment: There is one question for approach 1. To specify the resource-based access we have to choose the internet as an endpoint which is not recommended the way to store the sensitive data because we tried to do that but the Kibana dashboard was available to everyone or when we specify the specific source ips we  get the error "Message": "User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpPost on resource: mydomain".

Comment: And one thing more when we specify VPC as an endpoint then we can choose the option that this elasticsearch can be accessible to other accounts and then we specify the account id over there and tried to access the es in another account EC2 we were getting the same error "Message": "User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpPost on resource: mydomain". However, we allowed the IP in the security group.

Comment: Check this out to resolve "User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpPost on resource: mydomain" error: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/anonymous-not-authorized-elasticsearch/